# How to push twitter hashtag data using spring web project

Tags: java, spring

I can get real time twitter hashtag data using java application. Now I want to create spring web application and pass the always above filtered data to the front-end. So now I want to include above java class into my web application.

My problem was that method always run without coming front-tend request. How I develop it...

```
    import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.StallWarning;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class AnimalSL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("XR1hlPVFzQZaIaebKmKsuG3uK")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("ZJYjrtebpVhRzaoArSMnPda2dLpyIkDbIsX2a5QWUBh3sPwWOV")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("1459071614-lDCNBCuVlis2gOB3hg1k1PHwCngLxH47y8KNPHw")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("BYEvcWPLgrNM4e2HgrhONBTiaizGtfbv9fOur6U2ulNCC");

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
        String[] keywordsArray = {"#AnimalSL"};
        filtre.track(keywordsArray);
        twitterStream.filter(filtre);
    }

}
```

Using this code I can get real-time `AnimalLK` hashtag data. How does run this code in always into the spring web project. Because this code should be run always in my project... That is my question....???

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: apart from being somehow related to spring and twitter it is completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I added code ....